# how to set foreign key through the controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've got an address form nested into a user form but cant get the foreign key to fill. I've seen people suggest using a hidden field, but that seems to be a bad idea from a security standpoint. How exactly do you set the foreign key using the controller? Right now I'm getting Address user can't be blank error when I try to submit

MVC below

user\new.html.erb

```
<div>
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :rank %>
        <%= f.text_field :rank %>

        <%= f.label :firstName, "First Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :firstName %>

        <%= f.label :lastName, "Last Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :lastName %>

        <%= f.label :middleInitial, "Middle Initial" %>
        <%= f.text_field :middleInitial %>

            <%= fields_for :address do |a| %>

                <%= a.label :address %>
                <%= a.text_field :address %>

                <%= a.label :city %>
                <%= a.text_field :city %>

                <%= a.label :state %>
                <%= a.text_field :state %>

                <%= a.label :zip, "Zip Code" %>
                <%= a.text_field :zip %>
            <% end %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :dateOfBirth, "Date of Birth" %>
        <%= f.text_field :dateOfBirth %>

        <%= f.label :MOS, "MOS" %>
        <%= f.text_field :MOS %>

        <%= f.label :ets_pcsDate, "ETS/PCS Date" %>
        <%= f.text_field :ets_pcsDate %>

        <%= f.label :phoneNum, "Phone Number" %>
        <%= f.text_field :phoneNum %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.text_field :password %>   

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>  

        <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<h1>Users#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

Models

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :MOS, :dateOfBirth, :ets_pcsDate, :firstName, 
  :lastName, :middleInitial, :phoneNum, :rank, :email, :password, 
  :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address


  before_save {  |user| user.email = email.downcase  }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :rank,          presence: true
  validates :firstName,         presence: true, length: {  maximum: 15  }
  validates :lastName,      presence: true, length: {  maximum: 20  }
  validates :middleInitial,     presence: true, length: {  maximum: 1  }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email,         presence: true, 
                format: {  with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX  },
                    uniqueness: {  case_sensitive: false  }

  validates :dateOfBirth,       presence: true
  validates :MOS,               presence: true
  validates :ets_pcsDate,           presence: true
  validates :phoneNum,          presence: true
  validates :password,      length: {  minimum: 6  }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true


  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
  end
```

Address

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :city, :state, :zip

belongs_to :user

validates :address,         presence: :true
validates :city,              presence: :true
validates :state,               presence: :true
validates :zip,           presence: true
    validates :user_id,       presence: true
end
```

Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :show, :destory]
  before_filter :correct_user, only:[:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def new
@user = User.new
    @user.address.build
  end

  def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@address = @user.build_address(params[:address])
   if @user.save
    sign_in @user
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to B Troop!"
    redirect_to @user
else
    render 'new'
end
  end

  def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User removed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private
    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

Comment: is this form for a new user or? I saw there is validates :user_id,       presence: true

Comment: I don't believe you need the line `@address = @user.build_address(params[:address])` in the create action in the controller... Your form, combined with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` should be sufficient to set the address association.

Comment: Yes its for a new user. In other words clicking the sign up button on the home page brings up the form seen above. I know the validates :user_id is what is causing the missing address user id message...but i figured there was a way to set the user id in the controllers create method....dunno if thats right, im still really new to this

Comment: @rossta so i removed the line you mentioned and i was able to create the user, but at the console when i tried to access the address table i got nil returned. i used user.find_by_id(103) which returned the created user and then user.address which returned nil. maybe im doing something wrong but shouldnt user.address return the address model attributes that were set?

Comment: Ah - so you actually need `f.fields_for` instead of `fields_for` to set up params in the post request properly AND add `:address_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` list in `User`.

Comment: able to create the user but still nothing in the address table
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 104 LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 104, rank: "2lt", firstName: "john", lastName: "johnson", middleInitial: "j", dateOfBirth: "0012-12-1
2", MOS: "ads", ets_pcsDate: "0012-12-12", phoneNum: "1111111111", created_at: "2013-04-20 09:28:29", updated_at: "
2013-04-20 09:28:29", email: "jj@gmail.com", password_digest: "$"
..", remember_token: "4", admin: false>
> user.address
  Address Load (0ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."user_id" = 104 LIMIT 1
=> nil

Comment: im assuming i need something in the controllers create method to save f.field_for table to the address model, i just dont know what.

Comment: Nope, controller method is fine. I personally wouldn't validate the presence of `user_id` in `Address`... may be a problem since your user doesn't exist in the create action. Can you recreate `@user = User.new(params[:user])` on console and inspect `@user.errors`?

Comment: so i removed the user_id validation and it looks like everything is working. created a user and checked the address table and it was present in the console. im using the rails tutorial book by hartl as a guide and he has the user_id attribute validated in the creation of the microposts. its not a nested table though. can you explain why the validation causes it to break in a nested table but not for a standard one? without the user_id, how does rails associate the user and the address?

Comment: Regarding the reason for the validation fail, it seems that when creating nested models, the validations for all of them are run before any of them are saved. So in your case, when your address validations run, the user has not been saved and as such does not have an `id` (and hence address cannot have a `user_id`. (Also, on a side note, when using a nested form list this, you don't need to create the nested items, it happens automatically -- the `@address = @user.build_address(params[:address])` line in `users#create` is unnecessary.)

Comment: @rossta - your suggestion on the validation worked, if you put it down on the answer ill accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the user_id validation did the trick.