# Rails: nested_form_for <column> can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use the nested_form gem to create a dropdown that will show a list of chains and their locations. When the user clicks the submit button, the nested_form should create a new entry in a joiner table called users_locations. However, the form spits out an error as follows:

```
User locations user can't be blank
```

In other words, its complaining that the user_id is NULL and therefore it cannot create an entry in the table (because user_id is a required field in the user_locations table).

_form.html.erb (In the User view folder)

```
  <div class="field" id="location_toggle">
    <%= f.label "Location:", :class => "form_labels", required: true %>
    <%= f.fields_for :user_locations do |location| %>
       <%= location.grouped_collection_select :location_id, Chain.all, :locations, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: false %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add a Location", :user_locations, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-small" %>
    <br/>
  </div>
```

user.rb (model)

```
belongs_to :chain
has_many :user_locations
has_many :locations, :through => :user_locations
...
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_locations, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
validates_associated :user_locations, :message => ": you have duplicate entries."
...
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, ... , :user_locations_attributes
```

users_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save ? (redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.') : (render action: "new")
  end
```

Log shows:

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "user_locations" WHERE ("user_locations"."user_id" IS NULL AND "user_locations"."location_id" = 1)
```

Comment: I assume all the code in your `_form.html.erb` lives inside of a `form_for(@user)` block?

Comment: Yes! It lives inside <%= simple_nested_form_for(@user) do |f| %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're `user_location` `validates :user_id, presence: true` or something, right?

I had a look at this recently in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118417/how-to-set-foreign-key-through-the-controller-in-rails#comment23021960_16118417), it seems that, when creating nested models, validations for all objects to be created are run before any of them are saved, and thus even though your model will get have `user_id` set when it is saved, it cannot have it when validated.

To get around this you may want to disable the validation on creation, for example with:

```
# user_locations.rb
validates :user_id, presence: true, on: :update
```

Comment: You are correct in terms of the validation and this solution does work. However, it is unfortunate that on create I cannot validate that the user_id is present.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're blending `simple_form` with the default Rails form helpers and getting some odd behavior.  I haven't worked with `simple_form`, but my guess is that you can fix your problem by changing `f.fields_for` to `f.simple_fields_for`.

Here's an [example](http://hansay.com/2011/11/30/using-nested-form-with-simple-form/) that may help.

Comment: I switched it to f.simple_fields_for but it still didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!